# How to collect metrics (CPU, Memory, I/O) from docker cluster node container's?

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm, metrics, monitor

I have a manger node and two workers node connected via docker swarm.
When i use docker API "https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/" i can able to get (monitor) current node (manager node) container metrics like (CPU, memory uasge and I/O bytes), but i couldn't get container or service metrics from worker nodes. But i can get nodes details.

Is there any way to get (monitor) workers node container details from manager node?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) in every node (deploy global).

See an example of how to view data in Kibana: https://blog.codeship.com/monitoring-docker-containers-with-elasticsearch-and-cadvisor/